# Trying to resolve select relationships in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've nearly got what I am after, but I am now struggling to resolve the selection relationships in jquery to make the final part work. I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petercor/umcbs7oj/) which I have used to reach this stage and shows what I am trying to achieve.

If preferred, I can added the HTML & CSS here, but thought it easier to just leave them in the JSFiddle

This is the jQuery that is working on the first article mentioned below...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".more").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".long").fadeIn(2000, "linear");
        $(this).siblings(".short").hide();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".less").show();
    });
    $(".less").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".short").fadeIn(2000, "linear");
        $(this).siblings(".long").hide();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".more").show();
    });
});
```

To explain, the data is retrieved and there can be any number of records returned, some of which have an image. In each case, selecting the 'More...' link should display the longer text which should then show a 'Less...' link.

In the first article in the JSFiddle, it is almost working correctly, but I want the 'Less...' link to be appended to the end of the long text, just like the 'More...' link is to the short text. This works with the jQuery script but as you will see the 'Less...' link is in the wrong place.

In the second article in the JSFIddle, I have tried to correct it, but this is where I am struggling as I cannot get the relationship to get the selection to work get the 'Less...' link to show.

In the third article, there is no image, in which case, the full width of the available space is used when showing 'long' text data. I have the same issue here too.

Comment: You have a css rule setting it to not display - `.less, .long {display: none}`

Comment: @Jamiec and the code has `.show()` to show it... just the selectors are wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple option is to include the `.less` as part of the main text `.long`, then there's no need to hide/show it separately from the main text.

You can do this quickly with your css by adding:

```
.long .less { display: inline !important }
```

then the less appears in the correct place for your second text.

Of course, you'll then need to change the `.less` click code...

---

The better option is to not use `.siblings` as that restricts your html layout too much (any minor change to the layout breaks your script, as you've found).

While not completely independent of html, you can do this by going *up* to a parent container (".startArchive"), then *down* to your relevant code, eg:

```
$(".more").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".startArchive").find(".long").fadeIn(2000, "linear");
    $(this).closest(".startArchive").find(".short").hide();
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).closest(".startArchive").find(".less").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m. I've followed your suggestion, and it works great, but was not sure what I need the display: inline !important for as that then shows the long text and image at initial run time. A minor issue is that the 'Less...' is unselectable until the fadeIn is complete. I guess there's no way round that, and by shortening the time, it's fine. My simplified revised JSFiddle is at [link](https://jsfiddle.net/petercor/0u9fb93v/1/)

Comment: @peterc that just removes the need to show the .less separately.  It would be better to simply not hide it in your css.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m but I'm not quite sure how you mean here as it is in a separate span with a css class to colour and identify it.

Comment: You can keep it in a span/div, there's just no need for the `.find(".less").show()` if it's never hidden by itself.  Just hide/show it with `.long` if it's inside the `.long` div.

Answer (score 0):

What you have works, you just need to make sure your markup follows your select relationships.

Your less div is not a sibling in the lower articles, it is a child of the long text.

Move this to be a sibling and it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/umcbs7oj/1/

```
<span class="short"></span>
<span class="more">More...</span>
<div class="long wideText"></div>
<div class="less">Less...</div> <!-- This must be a sibling -->
```

Comment: Which is exactly how it is in the first section and the *exact* problem that is  trying to be solved.

Comment: His problem exists because his markup is not consistent, his selectors are for sibling elements, so he needs them to be siblings.

Comment: *"I cannot get the relationship to get the selection to work [to] get the Less"* - so the issue is with the selector.  He has the html he wants, but has the wrong selector (using siblings).  If he does what you say, that's the same as the first section and (as in your fiddle) the less appears in the wrong place as stated *"it is almost working correctly, but I want the 'Less...' link to be appended to the end of the long text"*

Comment: Thanks for replying @jimplode, but as freedomn-m says, it is gets back exactly to the issue I had.

Comment: my mistake, I misread the question. I assumed that you wanted it to behave as the first article. apologies

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
No need to have an extra Tag containing "Less..." Text. Just Simply change the text of Tag containing "more..." and check the Text of that tag in jquery.
In JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".more").click(function(){
                    if($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf("more") >= 0){
                    $(this).siblings(".long").fadeIn(2000, "linear");
                    $(this).siblings(".short").hide();
                    $(this).html("Less...");
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).siblings(".short").fadeIn(2000, "linear");
                        $(this).siblings(".long").hide();
                        $(this).html("More...");
                    }
                });
            });
```

```css
 body {
    font: 10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.headerArchive {
    color: #1a486f;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
}

.startArchive {
    clear: both;
}

.eventDateArchive {
    color: #1a486f;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.less,
.long {
    display: none;
}

.more,
.less {
    background: lightblue;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.narrowText {
    width: 500px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.wideText {
    width: 720px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="startArchive">
    <div>
        <span class="headerArchive">1st article heading</span>
        <span class="eventDateArchive">&nbsp;-&nbsp;20 Oct 2011</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <span class="short">1st short title. Congratulations to all the members bla bla</span>
        
        <div class="long">
            <div style="float:left;" class="narrowText">1st full title. Congratulations to all the members involved in this write up, especially to Fred Bloggs who did a major part in getting it into print. <a target="_blank" href="#">here</a>.
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="hover" href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-CNKqDrKxtQQ/VlstSBNlj5I/AAAAAAAAB3o/GGosdy1HJ60/s144-Ic42/PCAS%252520front%252520cover.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="more">More...</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="startArchive">
    <div>
        <span class="headerArchive">2nd article heading</span>
        <span class="eventDateArchive">&nbsp;-&nbsp;20 Oct 2011</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <span class="short">2nd short title. Congratulations to all the members bla bla</span>
        
        <div class="long text">
            <div style="float:left;" class="narrowText">2nd full title. Congratulations to all the members involved in this write up, especially to Fred Bloggs who did a major part in getting it into print. <a target="_blank" href="#">here</a>.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="long">
            <a class="hover" href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-CNKqDrKxtQQ/VlstSBNlj5I/AAAAAAAAB3o/GGosdy1HJ60/s144-Ic42/PCAS%252520front%252520cover.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <span class="more">More...</span>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="startArchive">
    <div>
        <span class="headerArchive">3rd article heading</span>
        <span class="eventDateArchive">&nbsp;-&nbsp;20 Oct 2011</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <span class="short">3rd short title. Congratulations to all the members bla bla</span>
        <div class="long wideText">
            3rd full text. Congratulations to all the members involved in this write up, especially to Fred Bloggs who did a major part in getting it into print. <a target="_blank" href="#">here</a>.
        </div>
        <span class="more">More...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Shashank Sharma, but this still gets me back to the issue I had in the first place of the Less... being on a separate line.

Comment: Have you tried to make the divs display property to inline-block

Comment: freedomn-m is correct you need to change the property of long and less as display:inline